# How can I split two groups as equally as possible in R?

Tags: r, testing, methods

I’m trying to do a basic A/B test, where I have to split my observations into two as equal groups as possible. The observations are based on session data from Google Analytics for different cities.

Therefore I need to create a random 50\50 split between the cities, but the split has to make the two groups as equal regarding sessions as possible. What would be my best option?

I’ve tried to perform a genetic algorithm approach to the problem, but when there’s only one variable, there must be an easier and faster way, right?

Comment: Why `python` if you want a solution with `r`?

Comment: You could look at a blocked randomisation.  That is, split the cities into groups based on your sessions variable then randomise within each block.  Be aware that restricted randomisation means that you have to analyse the data differently when you have finished your experiment.